# Redirect subdirectory of old domain to root folder of new domain via htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, root, subdirectory

I have gone through several domain iterations on a wordpress blog and want to get old links redirected to the new domain.  Initially the blog was in

```
olddomain.com/blog/
```

Now the blog is at the root level of

```
 newdomain.com
```

The old domain is set up as a domain alias of the new domain, it is not forwarded.

If anyone visits the site from

```
 olddomain.com/blog/
```

I need that to redirect to

```
 newdomain.com/
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running an apache web server you can just do it vía a 301 redirect in a .htaccess file

1. Go to you olddomain.com FTP root
2. Create or edit .htaccess file
3. Add following lines

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^blog/* http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
   ```

But this just redirect anything to the new domain, if you want to be "SEO friendly" (conserve canonical URLs) you will have to define a bit complex rule, take a look here: http://www.ksl-consulting.co.uk/301-redirect-examples.html

Comment: Why would you even put that as the answer?  It's obviously not what I was looking for. The page you linked only covers basic 301 redirects. No where in there does it cover subdirectory to root directory redirects.

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com [NC]     
    RewriteRule ^olddomain-subdirectory/(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]    

From what I can tell, that's the right way to do what I needed. It's working great for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Just create your .htaccess file and put it in the folder where you want to redirect from
   e.g put it in the **/blog** folder.
2. Add the following lines to your .htaccess file.

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} blog

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newside.com/newblog/$1 [R,L]

Answer (score 0):

If you're not strictly limited to .htaccess and have the option to modify `VirtualHost` configuration for `olddomain.com` you can add this to the configuration block:

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/(.*) http://newdomain.com/$1
```

This assumes `newdomain.com` is a separate `VirtualHost` and we're leveraging that for domain matching to prevent a redirect loop when the source is in a common folder.