# wordpress subfolder .htaccess redirect folder to domain root

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I developed my dev site in a subfolder in my root directory, and I've now got my production version now in the root directory. I want to use the dev .htaccess to redirect to the root version of the site.

I've followed the instructions in this link:
[Redirect subdirectory of old domain to root folder of new domain via htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343447/redirect-subdirectory-of-old-domain-to-root-folder-of-new-domain-via-htaccess)

this is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^newsite/* http://www.mydomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

At the moment it's just bringing up a 404 and staying at the same address without redirecting to the root.

I'm having trouble getting anything to respond at the moment, can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks
Frank

**EDIT**

So this is what it looks like with your suggestion Ravi, is this correct implementation?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^newsite(/(.*))?$ http://www.mydomain.com/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^newsite(/.*)?$ http://www.mydomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Would redirect `/newsite`, `/newsite/` and `/newsite/*` (but not `/newsitefolder`) to root `/`.

Comment: That isn't working for me.
I'm trying to paste code in here but it keeps failing on me.

Comment: As far as I've understood your requirement if a user enters `www.mydomain.com/newsite/newpage.php` s/he gets redirected to `www.mydomain.com/newpage.php`. If this isn't what you want please word your requirement again with an example.

Comment: ahh yep, its the whole folder i'm trying to redirect back to the root directory.

eg: www.mydomain.com/newsite/ or www.mydomain.com/newsite/newpage.php

I want to redirect to www.mydomain.com/

Any calls to any page within the www.mydomain.com/newsite/ directory.

Comment: newpage.php was just an example. I meant www.mydomain.com/newsite/* to www.mydomain.com/*. Just checked your updated comment. Did you mean newpage.php redirected to / i.e. index.php. I think maybe not. Please confirm.

Comment: Also check that `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` is not commented in your `conf/httpd.conf` file.

Comment: loadmodule is active. I want the latter, not focussing on a single page to page rule, I want anything that's within the newsite directory to be redirected to the root.